# Android JSON stop caching

Tags: android, json, caching

How can I stop caching when a JSON request is made? In my JSON request headers I have username and password and my problem is:

- first I put the correct data (correct username and password) -> The request is successful
- after the step from above I introduce a correct username but a wrong password -> The request is still successful and it shouldn't
- then I am closing my app with Force Stop and let the wrong password. Now the request fails which is Ok.

But I don't understand why I have to Force Stop the app in order to get the correct status of the request. The only thought that crossed my mind is that somehow the data is cached. If my thoughts are correct how can I prevent the caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out what the problem was. When I changed the password the session was not closed and it was connecting with the old data. So I had to make a "log out" using this code:

```
  client.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
  client = null;
```

And then I created a new Http Client.